# CakePHP 3 - Display tree structure in view with all information

Tags: cakephp, tree

I am just learning CakePHP and I wonder what is the best way of handling recursive tree data.
What I want is to display a threaded tree of some entity as nested lists in one of my views. 
Though I know I can let CakePHP create nested lists automatically from a tree, this only uses some field of my model.
I would like to create nested lists but be able to access multiple fields per list item to create links for example.

What I also tried was creating a recursive function in my view, but that doesn't feel to be the right way, also I cannot access the Html helper from within the scope of the function.

It would be great if someone could help me with that the CakePHP way. Thank you!

Comment: Read manual http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#finding-threaded-data and http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/behaviors/tree.html

Comment: Actually I have read both of them but none gives me a solution on how to display my objects recursively with all attached data.

Comment: If you need a powerful way, use the [Tree helper](https://github.com/dereuromark/cakephp-tools/blob/master/src/View/Helper/TreeHelper.php), see the internally linked doc on how to leverage it.

Comment: Wow, thank you @mark ! I didn't know how powerful this helper is. I will spend time on understanding its behavior tonight but *element* and *callback* look very promising to me